# Compare duplicate words and remove them from a string in php

Tags: php

A string look like this:

```
 $string = 'Super this is a test this is a test';
```

Output should be:

```
Super
```

I am trying to remove duplicate words completly from a string. What I have found is:

```
 echo implode(' ',array_unique(explode(' ', $string)));
```

but here is the output:

```
 Super this is a test
```

Thank you for a easy way to do this.

Comment: You will have to write something

Comment: @RiggsFolly do you mean I have to write more? Has the question not enough words? Thank you

Comment: @HakanSONMEZ Thank you but the output is wrong. What I want is -> delete the duplicate words complete.

Comment: You need to use it just array_diff in your solution

Comment: Like this?  echo implode(' ',array_diff(explode(' ', $string)));   its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `array_unique()` reduces duplicates to one value:

> Takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values. 
>   [src](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

You need to loop the array first (though can imagine a lot of creative array_filter/array_walk stuff possibly):

```
$string = 'Super this is a test this is a test';

# first explode it
$arr = explode(' ', $string);

# get value count as var
$vals = array_count_values($arr);

foreach ($arr as $key => $word)
{
    # if count of word > 1, remove it
    if ($vals[$word] > 1) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}

# glue whats left together
echo implode(' ', $arr);
```

[fiddle](https://3v4l.org/hqOsm)

And as a function for general project-use:

```
function rm_str_dupes(string $string, string $explodeDelimiter = '', string $implodeDelimiter = '')
{
    $arr = explode($explodeDelimiter, $string);
    $wordCount = array_count_values($arr);

    foreach ($arr as $key => $word)
    {
        if ($wordCount[$word] > 1) {
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }
    }

    return implode($implodeDelimiter, $arr);
}

# example usage
echo rm_str_dupes('Super this is a test this is a test');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use array functions and do this in one line without using `foreach`.

```
echo implode(' ', array_keys(array_intersect(array_count_values(explode(' ', $string)),[1])));
```

Comment: noice - knew there would be a solution using `array_*` functions only :) readability is a bit eh, but good solution for a one liner :)